# Web Service Error:

Tags: php, web-services

I'm trying to get some values from a WebService, but I'm getting some error messages when accessing from PHP web application or SoapUI.

When I access the service from Visual Studio .NET I get the right values, but I really need to access this from PHP.

Here is the error message:

```
<faultstring xml:lang="pt-BR">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ConsultaFretePedido'. End element 'xmlPedido' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'Pedido' from namespace ''. Line 6, position 51.</faultstring>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a tool like Fiddler to compare the HTTP requests being sent by Visual Studio and PHP; this should show up the differences which are causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the error:

> End element 'xmlPedido' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected.
>   Found element 'Pedido' from namespace ''. Line 6, position 51.

that means, that you have started with `<xmlPedido>` but ended with `</Pedido>`

look at the xml code, that the webservice is giving back, at line 6

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [SOAPui](http://www.soapui.org/) to check the WebService.